# Cisco VPN client on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cisco-vpn

I know you can no longer connect before login using Cisco VPN (version 5.0.07) on Win7 and Vista due to the change from GINA in XP to Credential Provider API.  Does this also disable the ability of staying connected after logging off Windows like could with XP?  I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: A very good question, I wish to logon to a machine, start the VPN, logoff and then back on again (pulling scripts from the DC! - don't ask) however the "options/Windows logon" menu does not appear on the 64 bit version of the Cisco client, so how do I maintain connection after logoff?.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, best choice is move to anyconnect if it is possible, VPN client is very near to EOL.
[Less than two years of support, and no new versions or upgrades](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps5743/ps5699/ps2308/end_of_life_c51-680819.html).

[In anyconnect, login before providing Windows credentials on Windows 7 is supported](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect22/administration/guide/22admin4.html#wp1006226), and  [licenses aren't very expensive](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Cisco-AnyConnect-Essentials-VPN-License-license/2623722.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pure Cisco VPN, and have a password on your router/switch, however your getting in or wether you have a server containing users, you will need to log in to a machiene to remain connected to the VPN if you are logging in like a windows user would, if you are on standalone machines then permissions may vary on machine to machine wether your comp remains connected to the VPN. Your answer over platforms should be yes, as long as you have a client.